# Conditionally inserting records into a table in multithreaded environment based on a count

Tags: sql, sql-server, multithreading, t-sql

I am writing a T-SQL stored procedure that conditionally adds a record to a table only if the number of similar records is below a certain threshold, 10 in the example below. The problem is this will be run from a web application, so it will run on multiple threads, and I need to ensure that the table never has more than 10 similar records.

The basic gist of the procedure is:

```
BEGIN
  DECLARE @c INT
  SELECT @c = count(*)
    FROM foo
    WHERE bar = @a_param

  IF @c < 10 THEN
    INSERT INTO foo
      (bar)
    VALUES (@a_param)
  END IF
END
```

I think I could solve any potential concurrency problems by replacing the select statement with:

```
SELECT @c = count(*) WITH (TABLOCKX, HOLDLOCK)
```

But I am curious if there any methods other than lock hints for managing concurrency problems in T-SQL

Comment: The question is why are you running it on multiple threads?  It is one set of write heads on the other end and one set of locks.  I can tell from you from  experience that you cannot write to table faster from multiple threads.

Comment: It will be run on multiple threads because it is run from a web application

Comment: I read a web application as one.

Comment: I want to do a procedure without lock hints is not a problem statement.  A table with repeating values is not even a 3NF.   http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: @blam I don't think this is an XY problem as the full problem is given (how can I manage concurrent inserts while ensuring that the db maintains an invariant). The additional constraint is a [technical problem arising from a social constraint](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265316/are-technical-problems-arising-from-social-constraints-on-topic). As for your 3NF concerns, the example is oversimplified to emphasize the problem. The real table has more columns and the repeating values are foreign keys, but this has _nothing_ to do with the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to use the [sp_getapplock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189823.aspx) system stored procedure. You can place your critical section logic in a transaction and use the built in locking of sql server to ensure synchronized access.

Example:

```
CREATE PROC MyCriticalWork(@MyParam INT)      
AS
    DECLARE @LockRequestResult INT
    SET @LockRequestResult=0

    DECLARE @MyTimeoutMiliseconds INT
    SET @MyTimeoutMiliseconds=5000--Wait only five seconds max then timeouit

    BEGIN TRAN

    EXEC @LockRequestResult=SP_GETAPPLOCK 'MyCriticalWork','Exclusive','Transaction',@MyTimeoutMiliseconds
    IF(@LockRequestResult>=0)BEGIN

        /*
        DO YOUR CRITICAL READS AND WRITES HERE
        */

        --Release the lock
        COMMIT TRAN
    END ELSE
        ROLLBACK TRAN
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `SERIALIZABLE`. By definition it provides you the illusion that your transaction is the only transaction running. Be aware that this might result in blocking and deadlocking. In fact this SQL code is a classic candidate for deadlocking: Two transactions might first read a set of rows, then both will try to modify that set of rows. Locking hints are the classic way of solving that problem. Retry also works.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comment.  Why are you trying to insert on multiple threads?  You cannot write to a table faster on multiple threads.

But you don't need a declare

```
  insert into [Table_1] (ID, fname, lname)
  select 3, 'fname', 'lname' 
    from [Table_1] 
   where ID = 3 
  having COUNT(*) <= 10
```

If you need to take a lock then do so

1. The data is not 3NF
   Should start any design with a proper data model
2. Why rule out table lock?
   That could very well be the best approach
3. Really, what are the chances?
   Even without a lock you would have to have two at a count of 9 submit at exactly the same time.  Even then it would stop at 11.  Is the 10 an absolute hard number?

Comment: Sure you can write faster to a table on multiple threads. Inserts generally don't block each other.

Comment: @usr I load data for a living and can tell you from vast experience no.  Unless you have partitioning going on it is one set of write heads at the other end.  So the insert don't logically block.  Those write head do physically block.

Comment: For an insert of a single value I doubt this is a deliberate attempt at multi threading for performance reasons. Probably multiple clients can connect to the database and attempt to insert rows with the same `bar` simultaneously.

Comment: @MartinSmith The question states "a web application".   I took that as one.

Comment: @usr I grant you that I can perform more writes in a given period of time from one thread than many.

Comment: That was added afterwards and it would be missing the point anyway. A web server gets multiple concurrent requests from different clients which is basically the situation I described.

Comment: @MartinSmith Still one app.  You could design one service that performs the inserts.  And I contend that is probably the best way to do it.  I would use a producer consumer BlockingCollection.

Comment: SQL Server already handles concurrency for you. Why would you want another layer with some home made code to do this? Assuming the OP has multiple web servers where does this sit? What is the benefit of it?

Comment: @MartinSmith I read it as one web app.  Even if it is multiple web server it can sit on the same box as SQL.  I do it in producer consumer because I have found it to be faster.  Martin this is not your question.

Comment: @Blam, this isn't your question either, and I never implied I was looking to speed up writes. I am just wondering if there is a way to solve concurrency issues in T-SQL without lock hints.

Comment: @user1672292 If you don't need to speed things up then what are the concurrency issues?

Comment: @Blam does it really matter? To clarify, the issues are exactly as Martin Smith described, the application uses threads to handle concurrent requests and will live on multiple web servers.

Comment: But if the writes are fast enough you don't have concurrency issues with even a tablock.